# Error on sharepoint server 2010 configuration

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, installation

I need to install sharepoint server 2010 on my developer pc with 64bit windows 7 OS. I followed microsoft instructions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx
Let me describe you on this. I copied all the files from the CD to my D: drive. Changed the config at D:\SharePoint Server 2010\Files\Setup and added the tag ''. Installed the prerequisites manually. Made specified changes to windows features, and run the setup.exe file. Selected 'Standalone' as installation type. The installation completed successfully.

While running configuration wizard, I got the message 'Configuration failed' saying 'Failed to create the configuration database'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me when installed my local development for SharePoint.  This link might be able to help. http://myspexp.com/2010/05/31/configuration-failed-when-installing-sp-2010-on-windows-7-failed-big-time-3

Answer (score 0):

While running configuration wizard, I got the message 'Configuration failed' saying 'Failed to create the configuration database'.

Please follow
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb9c345f-e830-40b8-a5fe-ae7a864c4d76&displaylang=en#filelist

Install Windows update, installation will work Fine

To install sharepoint on windows 7

Please follow
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14)